# Why is this happening? I show GeoJSON some coordinates with OpenLayers by request Ajax

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson, json, php, ajax

I want to display a GeoJSON on OpenLayers with a request from Ajax from the database:

I store in the `geojson` variable all the information and I icercated in two ways:
1. Directly from the already read variable -> in this case it works
2. From the external source in the json / geojson.json folder -> that does not work

```
<script type="text/javascript">



      proj4.defs('EPSG:31700','+proj=sterea +lat_0=46 +lon_0=25 +k=0.99975 +x_0=500000 +y_0=500000 +ellps=krass +towgs84=28,-121,-77,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs');                      
      ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

var geojson = $.getJSON('json/geojson.json', function(data) { });
var geojson = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"2","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[698282.236,377375.758],[698289.591,377372.136],[698183.88,377182.298],[698182.72,377197.045],[698282.236,377375.758]]},"crs":{"type":"EPSG","properties":{"code":"31700"}},"geometry_name":"wkb_geometry","properties":{"ogc_fid":"2","area_id":"2","building_id":"2","type":"test","area":"test","owner":"test","description":"test","administration":"test","address":"test","property":"test","layer":"Green Area","extendedentity":null,"linetype":"test","entityhandle":null,"text":"test","wkb_geometry":"01020000000500000000FED478544F2541002731087F081741408D972E634F25418195438B70081741295C8FC28F4E254181E92631790517410AD7A3708D4E2541027B142EB405174100FED478544F2541002731087F081741"}}]}

console.log(geojson);

var features = (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojson);

features.forEach(function(feature){
    feature.setId(undefined);
    feature.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:31700', 'EPSG:3857');
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM(),
        }),
        new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                features: features
            })
        })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
            attributionOptions:
                ({
                    collapsible: false
                })
        }).extend([
            new ol.control.OverviewMap(),
            new ol.control.FullScreen(),
            new ol.control.ScaleLine()

        ]),
        interactions: [
            new ol.interaction.DragRotateAndZoom(),
            new ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom(),
            new ol.interaction.DragPan(),
            new ol.interaction.DoubleClickZoom()
        ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([698282.236, 377375.758], 'EPSG:31700', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 14,
    })
});



    </script>
```

The GeoJSON content is the same does not differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ajax call doesn't return the geojson directly, it lets you specify a function to be called after the data has been loaded.  You must eith move the processing inside the `{ }` of `function(data) { }` or you can use a named function such as this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      proj4.defs('EPSG:31700','+proj=sterea +lat_0=46 +lon_0=25 +k=0.99975 +x_0=500000 +y_0=500000 +ellps=krass +towgs84=28,-121,-77,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs');                      
      ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

$.getJSON('json/geojson.json', processGeoJSON );

function processGeoJSON(geojson) {

  console.log(geojson);

  var features = (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojson);

  features.forEach(function(feature){
    feature.setId(undefined);
    feature.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:31700', 'EPSG:3857');
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM(),
        }),
        new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                features: features
            })
        })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
            attributionOptions:
                ({
                    collapsible: false
                })
        }).extend([
            new ol.control.OverviewMap(),
            new ol.control.FullScreen(),
            new ol.control.ScaleLine()

        ]),
        interactions: [
            new ol.interaction.DragRotateAndZoom(),
            new ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom(),
            new ol.interaction.DragPan(),
            new ol.interaction.DoubleClickZoom()
        ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([698282.236, 377375.758], 'EPSG:31700', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 14,
    })
  });

}

    </script>
```